# Help with a biconditional proof (Number Theory basic Inequality)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

For any positive real numbers x and y, x ≤ y if and only if x^3 ≤ y^3.

I know how to do the backwards implication, but I am stuck on how to do the forward implication. I move the x over to the right hand side of the inequality and then cube, but after expanding I am not sure where to go for I get 0 ≤ (−x^3 + 3x^2y − 3xy^2 + y^3).

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Use contradiction.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note that $y^3-x^3=(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)$.

Comment: Professor said to try direct proof not contradiction. I used y^3-x^3 for the backwards implication, but sadly I don’t see how to use it for the forward implication.

Answer (score 0):

For the forward implication, we can prove this by the formula $y^3-x^3=(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)$. Since $x \le y$, $y-x \ge 0$. Thus, we only need to prove that $x^2+xy+y^2 \ge 0$.

$$x^2+xy+y^2=(x^2+xy+\frac{y^2}{4})+\frac{3y^2}{4}=(x+\frac{y}{2})^2+\frac{3y^2}{4} \ge 0$$

Therefore, if $x \le y$, then $x^3 \le y^3$.